# C# member modifier must precede member type

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I am very new to programming

I am trying to understand the concept of Polymorphism is C#.
I wrote the simple following code, but i am getting an error

"Member Modifier 'virtual' must precede the member type and name"
"Method must have a return value"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace InheritanceEx1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Shape s = new Circle();
        s.draw();
    }
}

class Shape
{
    public void virtual draw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drawing Shape...");
    }
}

class Circle
{
    public override void draw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drawing Circle...");
    }
}
}
```

how can this error be eliminated?

Answer (score 0):

> "Method must have a return value"

Your method signature doesn't have a return type specified.

Your method must have a return type. Use void:

```
public virtual void draw()
```